# java look and feel and main

Tags: java, look-and-feel

If I use java look and feel in actionPerfomed after a button is clicked, the effect changing is not working correctly, instead it just changes slightly.

However, if I put the same code on main, it working correctly.

What would be the solution for this?

Comment: Changing the look and feel (how do you change it, BTW?) affect [newly created JFrames](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(boolean) )

Answer (score 3):

When you change the look and feel before you lay out the gui all GUI components know how to draw themselves. If you change it at a later stage you need to update the UI tree to make the changes propagate to all components:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfName);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
frame.pack();
```

See the [java documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic) about this.

This is an simple example that changes the look and feel when pressing the button:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Press to change") {

        int current = 0;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            LookAndFeelInfo[] lafs = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
            LookAndFeelInfo laf = lafs[current++ % lafs.length];

            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf.getClassName());
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
                frame.pack();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

If you don't want to `pack` the `frame` (change the size of it) just call `repaint` instead.